# Disable retryable writes when using updateMany

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In my mongoDb drivers I have retryWrites=true and I want to keep it like that.

```
mongodb://localhost/?retryWrites=true
```

However, when I use updateMany query

```
 .updateMany({}, { $set: { test_count: 0 } })
```

I receive an error

```
 errmsg: 'Cannot use (or request) retryable writes with multi=true' }
```

Is there a way that I can disable retryWrites when using updateMany but still keep it enable for other queries? I am hoping for something like this

```
 .updateMany({}, { $set: { total_question_asked_today: 0 } })
.option(retryWrites = false)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried .updateMany({}, { $set: { test_count: 0 } },{multi : true})  ?

Comment: Yes but still same error